# ordering xml node by child node text

Tags: c#, xml

I've been searching all the weekend, but haven't found any results, I'm looking for a program or C# code, that i select a file, and i can select a node, and the child node i want the mother node to be ordered by,

```
<SelectedProfile>
    <Name>Default</Name>
    <InstalledAssemblies>
        <LeagueSharpAssembly>
            <InstallChecked>true</InstallChecked>
            <InjectChecked>true</InjectChecked>
            <Status>Ready</Status>
            <DisplayName>Library - Common</DisplayName>
        </LeagueSharpAssembly>
    </InstalledAssemblies>
</SelectedProfile>
```

I want to select "LeagueSharpAssembly", and order all the "LeagueSharpAssembly" this by "DisplayName"

Any of u know something?

Answer (score 3):

Using Linq to XML

```
var result = x.Descendants("LeagueSharpAssembly")
        .OrderBy(r => r.Descendants("DisplayName").Single().Value);
```

This answer works, but I first misread the question, so the query should be:

```
var result=x.Descendants("LeagueSharpAssembly")
           .OrderBy(r=>r.Element("DisplayName").Value);
```

This was posted first by @RichardSchneider, so if you are going to use Linq to XML his answer should be accepted.

Comment: I don't know to code with linq, and newbie in c# (only know the basic) is is possible to do a method for me where i post to the method the file only? And it saves the xml to that file

Comment: I don't know how to do this without Linq @HugoAlves

Comment: Perhaps deserialize into objects and then manipulate in memory.

Comment: @JAT I have no issue with you changing your answer by copying my code, however pls mention that fact.

Comment: Sorry about that, let me explain, I misread the question, I started the linq query by searching for "SelectedProfile" elements. after I read your answer I re-read the question, and notice that the OP wanted only LueagueSharpAssembly, that's why I modified my answer, not copying yours, but addressing OP requirements. I'm leaving my old answer, and upvoting yours @RichardSchneider

Comment: That's a reasonable response.  Accepted convention is to just add an Update to the answer, instead of replacing original answer.

Comment: @RichardSchneider this looks better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq and XML to select and order the elements, then a simple `foearch` to process them.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("...");
var assemblies = doc.Descendants("LeagueSharpAssembly")
    .OrderBy(r => r.Element("DisplayName").Value);
foreach (var a in assemblies)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Assembly {0}", a.DisplayName);
}
```

Comment: I cannot figure out how it works, how do i save again for the document?

Comment: I've answered your posted question.  If you want to save look at the document (hint XDocumnent.Save).  If you still are unsure then post another question.

Comment: Error 102 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayName' and no extension method 'DisplayName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)           this is referent to the console "a.DisplayName"